# How to extract own symbol table

Tags: go, reflection, symbols

I'm looking at the package `debug/gosym` which has a type `gosym.Table`, allegedly a symbol table of a Go executable. Unfortunately, I don't see any ways of extracting the sysmbol table from the running program (Go reflection is lacking, and I need more info than it can provide, specifically, the names of exported symbols).

If this isn't possible generally, but can be done on Linux / for ELF binaries, that's an option too.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/debug/elf/ ?

Comment: or https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: @RickyA I want to list all symbols in a package. I am not interested in AST because I need this at run time. I'm reading the ELF parsing code now, but it's really a sub-optimal solution because not only will I need to parse a binary, I'll also need to find where it is.

Comment: @RickyA if you are interested to know why I need this information: it is needed to write (de)serializer for some data interchane formats, where the way many other Go libraries decided to implement this is not acceptable (i.e. I need to generate objects of the type given in the serialized payload instead of expecting the caller to know the type of the object). One such example is YAML (none of the existing Go libraries implements it correctly).

Comment: I dont think trying to deconstuct the sender binary is the solution here. Sounds more like you need a schema for your data, like protobuf.

Comment: Protobuf is an example of a format where you don't need what I'm asking for. Obviously, it is not a solution to my problem... Protobuf doesn't carry metadata with it and thus allows anyone to interpret it in whichever way you like: this is not the case with many other format that prescribe particular interpretation.

Comment: @RickyA Go has very lacking reflection facilities, so, the task sounds hard. But in languages like Java, Common Lisp, Python and lots of others this is a nobrainer... and so wanting to have something like this doesn't surprise anyone

Answer (score 1):

To get the symbol table of the currently running process in go (Linux):

```golang
var symTable *gosym.Table
var symTableLoadFailed bool

func loadSymbolTableLinux() {
    if symTable != nil || symTableLoadFailed {
        return
    }

    // Try to load from memory first
    const elfStartAddress = uintptr(0x400000)
    const maxSize = 0x10000000
    processMemory := (*[maxSize]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(elfStartAddress))[:maxSize:maxSize]
    exe, err := elf.NewFile(bytes.NewReader(processMemory))
    if err != nil {
        // Failing that, load a copy from disk
        exePath, err := os.Executable()
        if err != nil {
            symTableLoadFailed = true
            log.Printf("subvert: Error finding executable: %v", err)
            return
        }

        exe, err = elf.Open(exePath)
        if err != nil {
            symTableLoadFailed = true
            log.Printf("subvert: Error opening %v: %v", exePath, err)
            return
        }
    }
    defer exe.Close()

    lineTableData, err := exe.Section(".gopclntab").Data()
    if err != nil {
        symTableLoadFailed = true
        log.Printf("subvert: Error reading .gopclntab data: %v", err)
        return
    }

    addr := exe.Section(".text").Addr
    lineTable := gosym.NewLineTable(lineTableData, addr)
    symTable, err = gosym.NewTable([]byte{}, lineTable)
    if err != nil {
        symTableLoadFailed = true
        log.Printf("subvert: Error creating symbol table: %v", err)
        symTable = nil
    }
}
```

Also implemented here: https://github.com/kstenerud/go-subvert/blob/master/subvert.go#L165

Answer (score 0):

To get the symbol table of the current process you can use my [Elfie](https://godoc.org/bou.ke/elfie) package. It provides a [Table](https://godoc.org/bou.ke/elfie#Table) function that will parse the symbol table from memory and provide you a `gosym.Table` to work with. It currently only works for ELF binaries, and is highly unsafe, but give it a shot!